# get hidden value from loop div with jquery

Tags: jquery, loops

i have a search button. when the search button is clicked, it will generate this code :

```
<div class = 'clickedResult' title = 'click to see details'>
 <table>the result will br written in this table </table>
 <input type = 'hidden' class = 'form_id' value = '$form_id' /> 
 <input type = 'hidden' class = 'status' value = '$status' />
 </div> <br/>
```

this code is inside loop, the loop goes twice and the result of the loop is this

```
<div class = 'clickedResult' title = 'click to see details'>
 <table>the result will br written in this table </table>
 <input type = 'hidden' class = 'form_id' value = '14' /> 
 <input type = 'hidden' class = 'status' value = 'latest' />
 </div> 

<div class = 'clickedResult' title = 'click to see details'>
 <table>the result will br written in this table </table>
 <input type = 'hidden' class = 'form_id' value = '48' /> 
 <input type = 'hidden' class = 'status' value = 'updated' />
 </div>
```

if one of the table is clicked, it will do this (i use jquery)

```
$(".clickedResult").click(function()
  {
  $('.clickedResult input.form_id').each(function() 
      {
     alert($(this).val());
  });
  });
```

it will alert 14 and 48...  how to alert only 14 if i click the first table ? and if i click the second table it will alert 48 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".clickedResult").click(function() {
  alert($(this).find('input.form_id').val());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(this).children("input.form_id")` instead of `$('.clickedResult input.form_id')` to go through only the form_id that is a descendant of the div you clicked.

Considering your example, the code would look like this:

```
$(".clickedResult").click(function() {
    console.log( $(this).children("input.form_id").val() );
});
```

Also one might argue, that in your case using `.children()` instead of `.find()` is faster, because your input is only one dom level down from the div and `.children()` only searches one level deep, whereas `.find()` travels the whole tree to find all possible candidates.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `event` parameter in the click handler like here: http://jsfiddle.net/wE6JK/